# Xamarin forms: Left Side Outline Border on image

Tags: c#, image, xamarin.forms, portable-class-library

Hi I am developing an app using PCL Xamarin forms. I need to add an outline of about 5px to image. But only to left side with color and opacity.

[image]

I need the border to be of height as Image is. not more than it.

How this can be achieved?

[image]

If I use picker then-
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a grid and a box view

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />      
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="5" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  <BoxView WidthRequest="5" BackgroundColor="Black" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"/> 
  <Image Source="something.png" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"/>
</Grid>
```

The syntax may be abit off since I dont have VS with me to check but this should point you in the right direction.

Comment: If I use picker instead of this then, will the border go on to expanded list items or not?

Comment: ON using picker it covers the main picker only not the  items inside it. How to cover that?

Comment: Thanks for answer!